# Getting Error in Crahslytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using *SystemConfiguration* in *Reachability* class, but not sure where the crash is coming from

```
> libobjc.A.dylib    objc_msgSend + 16 1    SystemConfiguration 
> reachPerformAndUnlock + 640 2 CoreFoundation  
> __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 3 CoreFoundation

> __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524 4 CoreFoundation  
> __CFRunLoopRun + 804 5    CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 6   GraphicsServices     GSEventRunModal + 180 7    UIKit   
> -[UIApplication _run] + 684 8 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 208 9  MoveInSync   AppDelegate.swift line 38 main
```